# Personal documents in iPad Kindle app

Tags: kindle, kindle-app

Is there a way to make highlights to my "personal documents" on Kindle iPad app appear on http://kindle.amazon.com "my highlights" list?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon shut down `kindle.amazon.com`, so this is not possible.  Sorry.